# Combobox selecteditem if default "all" value should be -1

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2008

i have a c# WPF project that contains a combobox.
i have several items in the "selection", if i select any of those, then the value is correct (0 for the first item, 1 for the 2nd item and so fourth)
how can i add the first item as "all", and if user selects "all" then the value is "-1" ?
right now "all" is the first item, so it sets it to "0" value

thanks for anyone who can assist

Comment: You will never get an item with index = -1. Selected index of -1 means that no items are selected. Simply leave your ComboBox as is, with the "all" item at index 0, and test for selected index = 0 instead.

Answer (score 1):

-1 value states that nothing is selected try using SelectedIndex-1 as your value. If your reference SelectedIndex from xaml then some [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx) on binding will be required.

Answer (score 1):

instead of using the SelectedIndex use the SelectedItem and check if its the "All" value.

Example:

**the ViewModel**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
   public ObservableCollection<string> TheItems { get; set;}
   public string TheSelectedItem { get; set; }

   public MyViewModel()
   {
       TheItems = new ObservableCollection<string>();
       TheItems.Add("All");
       //Adding all the other value

   }

   public void SomeMethod()
   {
       if(TheSelectedItem=="All")
       {
          //Do whatever needs to be done 
       }
   }
}
```

**the View**

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding TheItems}" SelectedItem="{Binding TheSelectedItem}"/>
```

Comment: and if it is "all" value? i am still learning, maybe you have the code i need to use? etc